# Pattern matching in javascript text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text with patterns like %text% inside.
How can I get this patterns in javascript to wrap them in spans and changing color?

Thanks!

Comment: This is obscure. Can you be more specific than `like %text%`?

Comment: @crush, it might also contain numbers `like %text2%`. Does that help?

Comment: What is the significance of the `%` in the string? Is that part of the string, or is it meant to be a wildcard character? Are you just saying you want anything that is surrounded by `%` to be matched?

Comment: @gbtimmon: How do you know that it might have numbers?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I think it was sarcasm.

Comment: @Mathletics: Either my sarcasm detector is busted, or it wasn't very good sarcasm >.>

Comment: @RocketHazmat likely the latter. All systems normal.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'Some text with patterns like %text% inside.';

str = str.replace( /%([^%]+)%/g, '<span style="color: blue">$1</span>' );    
// Some text with patterns like <span style="color: blue">text</span> inside.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Regex](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp)

```
if (String.match(/text/gi)) {
    //wrap span around String and change color of CSS
}
```

Comment: I think what he is trying to do is use `%` as a "token" delimiter. For example, in the string: `Hi, %Jack%. Welcome to the site.`, it would replace `%Jack%` with `<span>Jack</span>`. Your approach is right, it just needs to include matching the `%` I believe.

Comment: my bad I thought it was a wildcard like in SQL. MikeM has the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern between `%`s is always pure text (excluding spaces etc.), you can do something like this:

```
text = text.replace(/%\w*%/g, function (txt) {
    return '<span style="color: red">' + txt.substring(1, txt.length-1) + '</span>';
});
```

Though MikeM's matching pattern is far ahead of mine, I leave this answer to show, how you can also use a function to manipulate the matched string, or even get some other stuff done, depending on the match.

Comment: Could easily add support for numbers too. I think the main thing would be to not allow spaces. Otherwise: `Hello, %Jack% what is %your profession%?` could match: `Jack`, `what is`, and `your profession`.

Comment: Why use `.substring()` when you can use capture groups?  `text.replace(/%(\w*)%/gi, '<span style="color: red">$1</span>');`  Also,

Comment: `\w` includes numbers.

Comment: MDN: "The following properties are deprecated. _This does not affect their use in replacement strings_:".

Comment: @Teemu: `$1 - $1` are deprecated as a property the regex object itself, ***not*** when used in a replacement string.  `'<span style="color: red">$1</span>'` works, and will continue to.

Comment: I see... Also learnt something, MikeM's pattern seems to find anything, +1 for MikeM : )